# Sequential Forms in web.py

Tags: html, forms, templates, web.py

I am trying to write a web interface to start a recording or playback process. I am using web.py and have one controlling python script (code.py) and three templates (main.html, record.html and playback.html) in a templates directory. The main page shows a form for playback and a form for recording, each with a button, which loads the relevant template with entered data when pressed. I would like to be able to cancel these processes and return to the main screen, so I have a form containing a 'Cancel' button which is rendered in both the record and playback templates. However, when I press this button. nothing happens. Any ideas would be appreciated.

code.py:

```
import web
from web import form
import os
import glob
import socket

render = web.template.render('templates/',
     globals={'os':os, 'glob':glob, 'form':form})

urls = ('/*', 'index')

recordForm = form.Form(
    form.Dropdown(name = 'rmode',
        description='Recording Mode:',
        args=<a list of tupels>),
form.Button('Record'),
)


os.chdir("/home/stingray/Documents/")

playbackForm = form.Form(
form.Dropdown(name='pmode',
     description='Playback Mode:',
     args=<a list of tupels>),
form.Dropdown(name='pfile',
     description='Playback File:',
     args=[(file,file) for file in glob.glob("*.*")]),
form.Button('Playback'),
)

cancelForm = form.Form(
form.Button('Cancel'),
)

class index:
def GET(self):
    r = recordForm()
    p = playbackForm()
    return render.main(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()),
        'Not Present',r,p)

def POST(self):
    formData = web.input()
    c = cancelForm()
    try:
        return render.record(formData.rmode,c)
    except AttributeError:
        return render.playback(formData.pmode,formData.pfile,c)

if __name__ == "__main__":
app = web.application(urls, globals())
app.run()
```

main.html

```
$def with (ipAddress,linkStatus,recordForm,playbackForm)

<html>
<title>
    Test Bridge Control - Main
</title>
<body>
    <center>
        <b>Test Bridge Control</b><br><br>

        <form method="POST">
            $:recordForm.render()
        </form>

        <br>

        <form method="POST">
            $:playbackForm.render()
        </form>

        <br> 

        Test bridge IP address: $ipAddress<br>
        Link status: $linkStatus<br>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

record.html

```
$def with (mode,cancelForm)

<html>
<title>
    Test Bridge Control - Record
</title>
<body>
    <center>
        Recording in mode $mode <br>

        <form method="POST">
            $:cancelForm.render()
        </form>

    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

And playback.html is very similar to record.html. Note that even though I'm not validating the form data, I can still access it - form entries appear in the rendered record.html and playback.html.

[EDIT] Should probably emphasize that searches for similar issues haven't been successful; no-one else seems to be trying to use multiple forms one after the other (or if they are, they're succeeding).

[EDIT] Doesn't appear to be a problem in Firefox 18 running in Fedora, originally seen in IE9 in Windows 7, which is probably what it will have to work in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an IE problem. Apparently IE9 does not treat buttons as being of type "submit" unless explicitly stated. Bizarrely the buttons in main did work as submit then stopped. All are now working after adding type="submit" to the button's declaration.